# what is Jquery $(this).val() equivalent in AngularJS? and How to set input field value to zero if input field is empty after updating?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

```
<script>
$(document).on('change', '.botentry', function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).val(0);
    }
});
</script>
```

and my html code is

```
 <tbody id=" tbody_Buid" ng-if="cstate!=''">
    <tr ng-repeat="b in BottomsUpData | filter:{qtr: cqtr, state: cstate} | filter:searchData | orderBy:['-mtmsegment','bizgroup']" style="text-align:center">
      <td><div>{{b.bizgroup}}</div></td>
      <td><div>{{b.mtmsegment}}</div></td>
      <td><div>{{b.family}}</div></td>
      <td><div>{{b.series}}</div></td>
      <td><div>{{b.formfactor}}</div></td>
      <td><div><span ng-if="!b.freeze.m1 || !b.m1.isEdit">{{b.m1.value}}</span><input class="botentry" ng-if="b.freeze.m1 && b.m1.isEdit" ng-model="b.m1.value" ng-blur="buTotCalc()" type="number" /></div></td>
      <td><div><span ng-if="!b.freeze.m2 || !b.m2.isEdit">{{b.m2.value}}</span><input class="botentry" ng-if="b.freeze.m2 && b.m2.isEdit" ng-model="b.m2.value" ng-blur="buTotCalc()" type="number" /></div></td>
      <td><div><span ng-if="!b.freeze.m3 || !b.m3.isEdit">{{b.m3.value}}</span><input class="botentry" ng-if="b.freeze.m3 && b.m3.isEdit" ng-model="b.m3.value" ng-blur="buTotCalc()" type="number" /></div></td>
      <td><div>{{b.m1.value+b.m2.value+b.m3.value}}</div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

I added this code to avoid entering empty field in input box, but it's not working with AngularJs, Jquery value zero is not binding with angularjs ng-model.

Comment: Please define _"not working"_

Comment: for empty value you need to bind angular variable using ngmodel with input and set default value 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create  custom  directive (check-Empty) as given below and add this directive to your HTML code like this

```
<tbody id=" tbody_Buid" ng-if="cstate!=''">
<tr ng-repeat="b in BottomsUpData | filter:{qtr: cqtr, state: cstate} | filter:searchData | orderBy:['-mtmsegment','bizgroup']" style="text-align:center">
  <td><div>{{b.bizgroup}}</div></td>
  <td><div>{{b.mtmsegment}}</div></td>
  <td><div>{{b.family}}</div></td>
  <td><div>{{b.series}}</div></td>
  <td><div>{{b.formfactor}}</div></td>
 <td><div><span ng-if="!b.freeze.m1 || !b.m1.isEdit">{{b.m1.value}}</span> 
     <input class="botentry" ng-if="b.freeze.m1 && b.m1.isEdit" ng-model="b.m1.value" ng-blur="buTotCalc()" type="number"  check-Empty /></div></td> 
 <td><div><span ng-if="!b.freeze.m2 || !b.m2.isEdit">{{b.m2.value}}</span><input class="botentry" ng-if="b.freeze.m2 && b.m2.isEdit" ng-model="b.m2.value"  ng-blur="buTotCalc()" type="number" check-Empty /></div></td>
 <td><div><span ng-if="!b.freeze.m3 || !b.m3.isEdit">{{b.m.value}}</span><input class="botentry" ng-if="b.freeze.m3 && b.m3.isEdit" ng-model="b.m3.value"  ng-blur="buTotCalc()" type="number" check-Empty/></div></td>
</tr>
```

Add this directive to your code

```
myApp.directive('checkEmpty', function () { 
    return { 
        restrict: 'A', 
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) { 
            element.bind('change', function () { 
                if (element.val() == "") { 
                    element.val(0).triggerHandler('input'); 
                } 
            }) 
        } 
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

in angular js, you use `$scope`:

> You don't update the input, you update the model to which the input is
>   bound.

for example:

**your html**:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type='text' ng-model='input' ng-click="myFunction('some value')">
</div>
```

**your controller**:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.input = 1;
   $scope.myFunction = function(value) {
        $scope.input = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: I would say that since 1.5, you should not use $scope but use the controller.

Comment: I would say that you should use it as it suits your needs because angular is changing versions more often then socks.

Comment: No, angularjs won't change version again, 1.7 is in LTS.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass `$event` as parameter to your `buTotCalc` function and use `$event.target.value` to get the value of the element in question.

```
$scope.buTotCalc = function(event) {
  event.target.value = event.target.value || 0;
}
```